# Any other ObservableCollection<T> alike?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, binding, observablecollection

In WPF, we can use `ObservableCollection<T>` to binding to a `ItemsControl` so that it dynamically update the UI when the collection changed. Today I saw another `BindingList<T>` which can do the same thing like the `ObservableCollection<T>` does. But the `BindingList<T>` doesn't implement the `INotifyCollectionChanged`; so I feel I was wrong that an collection which implements the `INotifyCollectionChanged` interface can do this thing alike. Is there any explanation about this feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

But it implements [IRaiseItemChangedEvents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.iraiseitemchangedevents.aspx).

I think BindingList was designed with more complex DataBinding scenarios, that allow add and edit items from view.

INotifyCollectionChanged is only to tell, when the list changed.

WPF probably has spefic implementation to support BindingList.

Comment: Can I assume that only a collection that implements IRaiseItemChangedEvent or INotifyCollectionChanged interface can do the update list in dinding. Any others?

Answer (score 2):

[`BindingList<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679.aspx) can raise the [`BindingList<T>.ListChanged Event`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132742.aspx)

[`BindingList<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679.aspx)  implements [`IRaiseItemChangedEvents`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.iraiseitemchangedevents.aspx)